# Console Error : Unhandled Promise rejection: Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor called on non-object

Tags: angularjs, storybook, angular-storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

[image]

Running Angular + storybookjs and getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. For me a circular Module import caused the issue.

I found the issue by setting a breakpoint in NgModulesAnalyzer to break when `typeof target !== 'function'`

A few stackframes up I found the Module that caused the issue and replaced the import